# XSLT to find max and min date in the xml file

Tags: xslt

Below is the xml which am getting and I need to find the max date in case of "RetailExitDt" and Min date in case of "RetailExitDt". Could you please suggest how exactly we can get it with xslt 1.0?

```
   <note RetailExitDt="2014-07-30" RetailIntroDt = "2014-04-19">
    </note>
    <note RetailExitDt="2014-07-20" RetailIntroDt = "2014-04-09">
    </note>
    <note RetailExitDt="2014-07-10" RetailIntroDt = "2014-04-29">
    </note>
```

I was trying for the below snippet but it is failing

```
  <xsl:variable name="latest">
          <xsl:for-each select="note">
            <xsl:sort select="RetailExitDt" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="RetailExitDt"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$latest"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very nearly there, except that `RetailExitDt` is an attribute, not an element.

```
<xsl:sort select="@RetailExitDt" order="descending" />
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
  <xsl:value-of select="@RetailExitDt"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: My bad luck, I am still not able to load the same xml after making the mentioned changes. copying the whole xslt here to verify       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
 <xsl:variable name="latest">
          <xsl:for-each select="note">
            <xsl:sort select="@RetailExitDt" order="descending" />
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
  <xsl:value-of select="@RetailExitDt"/>
</xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$latest"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @user3656432 please don't post code in comments as they don't preserve formatting, instead _edit_ the original question to add the additional information.  In this particular case (a) you can't put `<xsl:value-of>` directly under `<xsl:stylesheet>`, it has to be inside a template, and (b) your real XML must presumably have a root element around the `note` elements (otherwise it wouldn't be well-formed) so you need to take account of that in the for-each `select` expression.